# The use of "were- should- had” at the beginning of sentences instead of “if”

Tags: word-order, conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

Conditionals in English are usually formed by using *if* with normal word order; but for the three past (subjunctive) forms *were*, *should*, and *had*, it is also possible to express the conditional through subject–auxiliary inversion alone, with no *if* in the conditional clause.

Does forming conditionals in this manner differ semantically from *if*-conditionals? Is some aspect of the conditional statement or the conditionality emphasised more in one version than in the other? Or are there differences in how and when they are used? Or are they simply completely interchangeable?

For example:

> If I were you, I would try it again
>   Were I you, I would try it again
>
> If I had seen it, I would have told you
>   Had I seen it, I would have told you
>
> If you should drink, don’t get behind the wheel
>   Should you drink, don’t get behind the wheel

Comment: For me, it's an old fashioned learned use, and it is purely a matter of style.  I might use it if I wanted to sound stuffy.

Comment: _Had_ is less stuffy than the others (particular in the more or less set phrase “Had it not been for the fact that…”), and it's also quite common to hear “Should you [choose/wish/want/etc.]” (as in _Mission:Impossible_: “Your mission, should you choose to accept it…”); but apart from that, my feeling is the same as Greg’s.

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate of a question about _“If I was” vs. “If I were”_? That's completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Fortunately there are some people like you watchful, but when you are ignored tells me “decision has  already been made and it is non changeable “   I think you deserve an answer  this site  is very helpful site to the extent that it could be used as a source to answer all English questions when the people search for an answer., .Now if they type my question on google or else  and it appears as a duplicate with no answer, it does not look good even though there are so many knowledgeable people cooperating and  giving their knowledge to the public by using this site ..

Comment: @Saeid Four people have voted to reopen the question so far—one more vote is needed, then it will be reopened. I’m going to edit your question into more idiomatic English; that will bump it to the top of the list, and a high-rep user will hopefully see it and cast the final vote to reopen.

Comment: Thank you  Janus : But I thought you need 5 people to mark it as a duplicate in the first place.

Comment: @Janus I know you tried to reopen the question and so far  we haven't received  one more vote,now my question is :why one person can close the question, but in order to reopen it vote of 5 people is needed? I think vote of more than one person should be required to mark it as a duplicate and close it .

Comment: Closing generally also requires five votes, but votes by moderators and ‘super users’ (users who have a gold badge in one of the question’s tags) count as five votes, so they can close a question with their vote alone.

Comment: @janus I think they have removed the duplication mark from my question, I noticed another one has been marked as a duplicate   by two moderators one with 14 gold and the other with one gold badge which is a better policy  in my opinion there is nobody in the world who doesn’t make any mistake or bad judgment so it has to be verified by at least one more person. ..Please   refer to A single term for the duration between sunrise and sunset? [duplicate]

Comment: You're right. I have removed the reference to the duplicate (which will also push the question back to the top of the front page where people are more likely to see it).

Answer (score 8):

The phenomenon mentioned here is often called Conditional Inversion in the linguistic literature. Here's an [interesting paper](http://lingphil.mit.edu/papers/iatridou/conditional_inversion.pdf) about it.

One difference between Conditional Inversion and *if* is that inversion is really only possible with those three verbs, as you note, and hence is usually only found with counterfactuals. Another difference is that inversion doesn't work well with the focus adverb *only*:

1. Only if I had thought that he was sick would I have called
   him.
2. *Only had I thought that he was sick would I have called
   him.

Those are my judgements and the judgements of the authors of the paper I linked to, and my guess is that they are in line with modern usage generally, though it would be good to check. The Iatridou & Embick paper gives some more potential contrasts. Their conclusion is that verb-initial conditional clauses can't be focused, and that "The use of inversion is meant to indicate the fact that the truth of the proposition in the antecedent is old [information]".

A side point is that in the recent history of English this type of inversion was possible with a lot more verbs, including *could*, *would*, *might* and *did* (Denison 1998: 298-300). This might account for the overall rather formal flavour of these examples, as Greg Lee mentioned in his comment.

Still, in a large number of situations the two constructions are completely interchangeable (for me at least).

Ref: Denison, David. 1998. Syntax. In Suzanne Romaine (ed), *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, vol. 4: 1776-1997, 292-329. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Additionally, it may be added that in many other Germanic languages, conditional inversion can be applied to just about any conditional, regardless of what the verb is. On the other hand, an inversed condition can in English be focused (if indeed it counts as focusing—I’m not sure) by a strengthening _even_ (“Even had they not done so…”), which utterly impossible in at least the other Germanic languages I consider myself proficient in.

Comment: The link to the paper does not seem to work anymore?

Comment: Thanks Matifou - I’ve updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

As George said earlier, these inversions are interchangeable and my opinion is that it puts more emphasis on the condition than the if-clauses. I'd say one normally uses it to sound more 'academic', to gain points in school essays and to look good and sound smart. The only thing I would add is that you can use 'should' to show a future possibility as well, not just in the example you gave. For instance, you could say:

Should I win the competition, I would donate the money to charity.

If you want to use an if-clause, you don't necessary need to include the 'should'.

If I won the competition, I would donate the money to charity.

To me, they sounds like an aspiration, a dream, or a possibility (which would be stronger in the first case than in the if clause). I would personally use 'Should I get this...' when I'm thinking there's a good chance that might happen. But it's a personal preference, otherwise I'd say they are completely interchangeable (with the exception of only if, but that's a different type of condition).

Hope this helped :)

Comment: For more certainty, I would use the present in the apodosis at least (which, with _if_, would require it in the protasis as well): “Should I win the competition, I will donate…” and “If I win the competition, I will donate…”.