# When does "Should" precede the subject?

Tags: should

I'm curious about this matter and have no true explanation for it. As I pinpointed in the title, when does **Should** precede the subject? I mean the example below (copied):

*Should your work habits not like...*

Why did **Should** come before the subject "**your work**"? Why wasn't it arranged as "***Your work should not habit like...***"? By the way, the sentence was on the beginning of the line.

Comment: "Should your work not habits like..." makes no sense. Even if *habit* were a verb, it wouldn't end *-s* there. This question is the only instance Google finds of "Should your work not habits like". Please check that you have transcribed the example -- or find a different one, like "Should your work not excel like Tommy's..."

Comment: "Should your work not habits like" is not grammatical English.

Comment: Oops, I didn't write the sentence right. Sorry, edited. If you want the literal sentence I saw, then here you go: **Should your work habits not be compatible with that concept**

But I think the example I gave and the original sentence are not different.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers:

**1)** It might be a question: *"Should we tell him the truth?"*

**2)** It might be a type of conditional protasis, in which the notion of "if" is implicit and the modal verb "should" and the subject have had their usual word order inverted: 
*"Should he be there, try to avoid him."* ( = "If he should be there, try to avoid him." = "If he is there, try to avoid him." )

See also: [The use of "were- should- had” at the beginning of sentences instead of “if”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233992/the-use-of-were-should-had-at-the-beginning-of-sentences-instead-of-if)