# to understand the sentence

Tags: grammar

- *From the manner in which I love this child, my Lord, you ought to know how I would have loved his elder brother had he proved worthy of any  mother's affection!*

İs the sentence grammatically correct? Why does 'he' come after 'had'?

Comment: Hello, CGU. Does this answer your question? [The use of "were- should- had” at the beginning of sentences instead of “if”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233992/the-use-of-were-should-had-at-the-beginning-of-sentences-instead-of-if) (conditional inversion)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. İt worked.